# How can i convert the following if statements into switch/case

Tags: c#

How can i convert the following if statements into switch/case

```
private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, c0)) { spotClick(0); }
   if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, c1)) { spotClick(1); }
   if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, c2)) { spotClick(2); }
   if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, c3)) { spotClick(3); }
}
```

Comment: 1. You can't, 2. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to convert it? If you are looking for help improving working code, use codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `var dict = new Dictionary<object, int> {{c0, 0}, {c1, 1}, {c2, 2}, {c3, 3}}; foreach (var kvp in dict) { if (ReferenceEquals(kvp.Key, sender)) { spotClick(kvp.Value); } }`

Answer (score 1):

How about you map the variable to the value and then call the value?  Like so:

```
Dictionary map = new Dictionary();
map.add(c0, 0);
map.add(c1, 1);
map.add(c2, 2);
map.add(c3, 3);

spotClick(map[sender]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we detaily examine your code, we see that you are comparing references of the two objects. Since the reference of one object cannot be equal to the reference of some other object then it appears that in this code could be used `if-else if` combination so it could look like this:

```
private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, c0)) { spotClick(0); }
   else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, c1)) { spotClick(1); }
   else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, c2)) { spotClick(2); }
   else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, c3)) { spotClick(3); }
}
```

`ReferenceEquals` method also returns true if both objects are null (check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)) which could produce that multiple comparisons are true (multiple sporClick calls executed), but in normal conditions, we cannot expect that `sender` is `null` since `Click` event fired , therefore this is a legit code and equivalent to one you posted. Such code could be converted to use `switch` statement if the c0, c1, c2 and c3 were constant-expressions but as we can see, they are variables that reference the objects of the types derived from  `Control` class and as such could not be used within `case` (check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). Therefore you **can't** convert this code to `switch/case`

Answer (score -2):

converting to a switch is not the most optimized way because they're different values for each "if". You could however do a for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, "c" + i)) { spotClick(i); }
}
```

I guess concatenating "c" + i in C# would be something like

string.Format("c{0}",i);

Comment: You cant use `c+i` to build variable names in C#

Comment: @darthmaim , yeah my bad, I thought we where talking about Javascript here.

Comment: @t.niese, yeah missing the "c" + i, but other than that works.